# What does the HTTP header Pragma: Public mean?

Tags: http, pragma

What does the HTTP header Pragma: Public mean?

Answer (score 44):

According to the [standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), *Pragma* is implementation dependent (section 14.32), except for **no-cache** because of its wide use. **Cache-Control** (section 14.9) is the proper way to control caching. This is what the standard says for a `Cache-Control: public`:

> Indicates that the response MAY be
>   cached by any cache, even if it would
>   normally be non-cacheable or cacheable
>   only within a non- shared cache.

Comment: Thanks but there are many instances of people coding so that a header is sent that contains only Pragma: Public.  What does this mean to any major browser?

Comment: The same that "Cache-Control: public", ie, that they MAY cache the information in that response.

Comment: It means coders should stop using it because it's probably not serving any purpose

Answer (score 11):

Also, "Pragma: Public" is used in Google App Engine applications to enable caching of responses within its Edge Cache.

See [Details on Google App Engine's caching proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947643/details-on-google-app-engines-caching-proxy)

Answer (score 8):

Useful when you come across this error: http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/1020. IE 8 & less seems to like to cache things when they are on a SSL server. Putting 'Pragma:public' helps with: "Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later"