# Google Apps-script UrlFetchApp.fetch returning cached copy

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using UrlFetchApp in a google apps script to perform a get, as follows:

```
var optAdvancedArgs = {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {"Cache-Control": "no-cache", "Pragma": "no-cache"}, 
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, optAdvancedArgs);
```

Despite my attempt to disable the cache in the headers, the response I get is always a cached copy. If I perform a wget in my console using the same url, I see receive an up to date version.

My question is: How can I *really* disable the cache when performing a UrlFetchApp.fetch? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: What URL are you trying to fetch and how are you confirming its a cached copy? This is strange indeed. The UrlFetch happens from the Google Data Centers and could be something funny happening with the data source trying to cache for that IP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to overcome this issue by using "max-age=0" in my Cache-Control header, e.g.:

```
var url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
var options =
  {
    // Ensure we get a fresh copy of the site every time.
    headers : {'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0'}
  };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
```

It sounds like Google App Engine has a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981688/does-url-fetch-use-gaes-proxy-cache). Someone [opened an issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=739) however it appears to have been closed.