# php header file path

Tags: php

I'm asking for a solution how to make PHP download a file without redirect and without reading file source like in this example:

```
if(1 == 1)
{
    header("Content-Type: application/xml");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.xml;" );    
    $file = file_get_contents("file.ext");
    echo file;
}
```

I need solution for download witout `file_get_contents` make the download like `mod_rewrite`.

Thanks

Comment: `PHP download file without redirect and without read file source`  -- it is impossible

Comment: @zerkms, no its not: mod_xsendfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Apache with the X Send File module https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

> mod_xsendfile is a small Apache2 module that processes X-SENDFILE
>   headers registered by the original output handler.
>
> If it encounters the presence of such header it will discard all
>   output and send the file specified by that header instead using Apache
>   internals including all optimizations like caching-headers and
>   sendfile or mmap if configured.
>
> It is useful for processing script-output of e.g. php, perl or any
>   cgi.

Comment: Hello sir, thank's for your answer my question please if I use this module can user know the direct link I need it hidden

Comment: @user533178, no you never send the link to the client. You send a header with PHP, and then Apache picks it up and redirects the download automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Pragma: public"); 
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.ext;" );    
readfile("file.ext");
```

Comment: Why is `header("Pragma: public");` required?

Comment: You can read here :) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920781/what-does-the-http-header-pragma-public-mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920781/what-does-the-http-header-pragma-public-mean)

Comment: That does not describe a requirement for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have PHP send the file straight out the output, instead of into a var with [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

**EDIT**

I would recommend instead to read and pass-through the data block at a time, which should perform better because it doesn't have to read the whole file before starting output.

```
if ($f = fopen($file, 'rb')) {
    while(!feof($f) and (connection_status()==0)) {
        print(fread($f, 1024*8));
        flush();
    }   
    fclose($f);
}
```