# Opening file content resource (Excel) of JasperReports Server / Tomcat with Internet Explorer displays binary data inline

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, tomcat, http-headers, jasperserver

- `Content-Type`/`Accept`/MIME HTTP headers issue?
- JasperReports Server (5.2.0) (update 2014-08-20/21: **5.5.0 & 5.6.0** alike)
- running on **Tomcat 7**
- clients tried

  - **Internet Explorer**

    - 5.2.0 tests (default below)

      - **9.0.8112.16421 64bit (default below)**
      - 11.0.9600.17105 64bit
    - 5.5.0 tests (update 2014-08-20)

      - 8.0.7601.17514
      - 9.0.8112.16421
      - 10.0.9200.16384
  - Firefox 28.0
  - Chrome (34.0.1847.131 m)

If I navigate in the **JasperReports Server Web GUI** to my previously uploaded *Inhaltsresource* (*content resource*), a ***.xlsx Excel** document, it **works well in Firefox and Chrome, by offering to save or open the file, but** it **fails in Internet Explorer, by displaying the files binary content in the tab :-(**

I did quite some research, but could not find a definitive cause, although some points may point at the cause:

(more general observation:)

- the IEs/Jasper GUIs sent **HTTP request header (`ACCEPT` string) seems to be wrong/incomplete/IE-incompatible**

  - (thus) the **Jasper Servlets HTTP response header (`Content-Type` string) seems to be wrong/incomplete/IE-incompatible**

(when thinking about this a little deeper:)

- **shouldn't the JasperServer itself (or the Tomcat as the container to a certain degree on delivery) try to determine the to-be-delivered content type?**

  - either by letting the user-set it manually or better by determining it **via heuristics (file extension, content parsing, ...)**

    - this way it could also be **stored along with the file** (I would only do it if the user want's to override the result of the heuristically determined type)
  - since the filename or the URL already easily indicate that it is a *.xlsx file and the content starts with `PK...` it already strongly indicates that it really is a (ZIP-packed) Excel file
  - so I would see **two basic ways this should work in general**...

    - the **request header (Jasper-delivered GUI page) should define the content type explicitely** (maybe only, if it can't be easily determined by the response functionality itself)
    - (generally maybe more appropriate:) the **response header (Jasper/Tomcat server logic) should set the requested, correct or estimated content-type explicitely**

      - **looking at the header responses of IE or FF one can clearly see that no `Content-Type` is set here, although the REST-API call further down has it set (and it works there) to `application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8`**

Here are **details that I checked already**:

- **ok**: the **HTTP response headers for FF and IE do not significantly differ** to me (although the request headers are quite different) (see below), thus indicating some issue with the magic of result content detection (where FF and Chrome seem to be better in this case)
- the **HTTP Headers of IE and FF** request/response cycles:

  - **IE** 9 (captured with onboard dev tools):

    - **request** header

      ```
      Anforderung        GET http://...:8080/jasperserver/fileview/fileview/....xlsx? HTTP/1.1
      Accept             application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*
      Accept-Language    de-DE
      User-Agent         Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
      UA-CPU             AMD64
      Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
      Host               ...:8080
      Proxy-Connection   Keep-Alive
      Cookie             userTimezone=Europe/Berlin; JSESSIONID=0FEF6E9F46EB2202A041A0A6F37B249A; userLocale=de_DE; treefoldersTree=1%7Copen%3B4%7Copen%3B5%7Copen%3B8%7Copen%3B; lastFolderUri=/...
      ```
    - **response** header

      ```
      Antwort             HTTP/1.0 200 OK
      Server              Apache-Coyote/1.1
      Cache-Control       no-store
      Expires             Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
      P3P                 CP="ALL" 
      Pragma    
      Content-Language    de-DE
      Content-Length      453242
      Date                Thu, 08 May 2014 10:54:46 GMT
      X-Cache             MISS from ..some-proxy-host..
      X-Cache-Lookup      MISS from ..some-proxy-host..:8080
      Via                 1.1 ..some-proxy-host..:8080 (squid/2.7.STABLE8)
      Connection          keep-alive
      Proxy-Connection    keep-alive
      ```
  - **FF** (captured with HttpFox addon)

    - **request** header

      ```
      (Request-Zeile)    GET /jasperserver/fileview/fileview/....xlsx? HTTP/1.1
      Host               viasaxinfo.list.smwa.sachsen.de:8080
      User-Agent         Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
      Accept             text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
      Accept-Language    de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
      Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
      Referer            http://...:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=searchFlow
      Cookie             userLocale=de; userTimezone=Europe/Berlin; JSESSIONID=E3989F65A4198047DA87FBB7BB73ABBA; treefoldersTree=1%7Copen%3B4%7Copen%3B5%7Copen%3B8%7Copen%3B; lastFolderUri=/...
      Connection         keep-alive
      ```
    - **response** header

      ```
      (Status-Zeile)    HTTP/1.0 200 OK
      Server            Apache-Coyote/1.1
      Cache-Control     no-store
      Expires           Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
      P3P               CP="ALL" 
      Content-Language  de
      Content-Length    453242
      Date              Thu, 08 May 2014 11:00:48 GMT
      X-Cache           MISS from ..some-proxy-host..
      X-Cache-Lookup    MISS from ..some-proxy-host..:8080
      Via               1.1 ..some-proxy-host..:8080 (squid/2.7.STABLE8)
      Connection        keep-alive
      Proxy-Connection  keep-alive
      ```
- **ok**: the **compatibility view in IE** does not help it
- checking potential HTTP response problems (which differ)

  - **`Pragma`**: should have the same meaning like `Cache-Control: Public`

    - [What does the HTTP header Pragma: Public mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920781/what-does-the-http-header-pragma-public-mean)
  - **`Content-Language`**: shouldn't matter here I guess
- checking potential HTTP request problems

  - **order of request header rows** shouldn't matter
  - **`Accept`**: problematic?

    - seems ok looking at the specs http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
  - **`Accept-Language`**: shouldn't matter
  - **`Cookie`**: content shouldn't matter
  - **`Proxy-Connection`**: disabling/enabling proxy settings did not change something
- **ok**: **MIME type setup in `tomcat7/conf/web.xml`**

  ```
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>xlsx</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  ```

  - putting it as well under `jasperserver/WEB-INF/web.xml` does not help either
  - some more details about this can be also found here:

    - http://blogs.adobe.com/techcomm/2012/11/handling-xlsx-docx-and-pptx-baggage-files-when-publishing-to-robohelp-server.html
    - http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php
- using the **[Rest API](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/rest-jasperreports-server-downloading-report-files-python-27-and-requests) (`.../jasperserver/rest/resource/...`) works in both FF and IE**

  - IE 9:

    - with `fileData=true` (brings up a dialog whether to open or save the file where opening works as expected)

      - HTTP request header

        ```
        Anforderung        GET http://...:8080/jasperserver/rest/resource/....xlsx?fileData=true HTTP/1.1
        Accept             text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
        Accept-Language    de-DE
        User-Agent         Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)
        UA-CPU             AMD64
        Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
        Host               ...:8080
        Proxy-Connection   Keep-Alive
        Cookie             userTimezone=Europe/Berlin; userLocale=de_DE; JSESSIONID=1B91EC2172C438C51A551CB967A3148D; treefoldersTree=1%7Copen%3B4%7Copen%3B5%7Copen%3B7%7Copen%3B10%7Copen%3B; lastFolderUri=...; foldersPanelWidth=239
        ```
      - HTTP response header

        ```
        Antwort          HTTP/1.0 200 OK
        Server           Apache-Coyote/1.1
        Cache-Control    private
        Expires          Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
        P3P              CP="ALL" 
        Content-Disposition    attachment; filename=....xlsx
        Content-Type     application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8
        Date             Fri, 09 May 2014 12:44:05 GMT
        X-Cache          MISS from LIST-SRV-PROXY03
        X-Cache-Lookup   MISS from LIST-SRV-PROXY03:8080
        Via              1.1 ...some-proxy-host...:8080 (squid/2.7.STABLE8)
        Connection       close
        ```
    - without `fileData=true` returning the expected resource meta data XML (displayed inline)

      ```
      <resourceDescriptor name="....xlsx" wsType="contentResource" uriString="/....xlsx" isNew="false">
       <label><![CDATA[....xlsx]]></label>
       <creationDate>1399636098445</creationDate>
       <resourceProperty name="PROP_RESOURCE_TYPE">
         <value><![CDATA[com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.domain.ContentResource]]></value>
       </resourceProperty>
       <resourceProperty name="PROP_PARENT_FOLDER">
         <value><![CDATA[/...]]></value>
       </resourceProperty>
       <resourceProperty name="PROP_VERSION">
         <value><![CDATA[0]]></value>
       </resourceProperty>
       <resourceProperty name="PROP_SECURITY_PERMISSION_MASK">
         <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
       </resourceProperty>
       <resourceProperty name="CONTENT_TYPE">
         <value><![CDATA[contentResource]]></value>
       </resourceProperty>
       <resourceProperty name="DATA_ATTACHMENT_ID">
         <value><![CDATA[/....xlsx]]></value>
       </resourceProperty>
      </resourceDescriptor>
      ```

I spent quite some time on this, but neither googleing (I wonder why nobody else seems to have this issue although it looks very common to me) nor various debugging did help. Maybe I would have to play in detail with the related Jasper classes to debug further, but maybe somebody else had this issue as well or knows a solution?

Comment: posted this in the Jasper forum as well in hope somebody there can help: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/826574/opening-file-content-resource-excel-jasperreports-server-tomcat-internet-explorer (I'll update any findings here as well)

Comment: added test results with latest community release 5.5.0 where it is still not working :-( ... we'll try with the 5.6.0 commercial demo release as well

Comment: may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535128/wrong-mime-type-on-jasperreports-server-response + http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreportsr-server/issues/3716

Comment: created bug report: http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/3819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems there is a manual workaround possible: http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreportsr-server/issues/3716#comment-808481

> we **implemented a servlet filter class** to try to set the Content-Disposition **header of the response** **in the cases when we knew that the MIME type was wrongly set**. As we knew that the response was flushed after being processed by the web service end point, we set the header BEFORE being processed as **`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='filename.extension'`**. This turned out to work, and we were able to download the file with an appropriate file extension.

but they also mention that it would work with a *v5.6.0* although it did not in our tests (see comment above: [Opening file content resource (Excel) of JasperReports Server / Tomcat with Internet Explorer displays binary data inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567429/opening-file-content-resource-excel-of-jasperreports-server-tomcat-with-inte#comment39654621_23567429))

> v5.6.0, and apparently on this release the MIME type of the response was correctly set, so we finally get to a proper solution for our problem.